# Find the cell adresses for each cell that starts with a specific number

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for a code, that can find each cell that starts with the number "2347" in column L. I want to get the cell adresses for these cells and display it in a MessageBox for example "Msgbox: Cells L3500:L3722 has a value starts starts with "2347" "

```
Sub Findrow()

Dim MyVal As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long


MyVal = LEFT(c.Value,4) = "2347" _
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row 

For Each c In Range("L2:L" & LastRow) 

If c.Value = Myval Then
```

This is my code so far. Hope someone can help me!

Comment: `c.Address` will return the address for `C`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using arrays is quite fast

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FindIDInColL()

    Const VID = "2347"   'Value to find

    Dim ws As Worksheet, arrCol As Variant, found As Variant

    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'Or Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
    arrCol = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, "L"), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp))
    ReDim found(1 To UBound(arrCol))

    Dim r As Long, f As Long, msg As String

    f = 1
    For r = 1 To UBound(arrCol)             'Iterate vals in col L, excluding header row
        If Not IsError(arrCol(r, 1)) Then   'Ignore errors
            If Len(arrCol(r, 1)) > 3 Then   'Check only strings longer than 3 letters
                If Left$(arrCol(r, 1), 4) = VID Then    'Check first 4 letters
                    found(f) = r + 1        'Capture rows containing value (header offset)
                    f = f + 1
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If f > 1 Then                           'If any cells found
        ReDim Preserve found(1 To f - 1)    'Drop unused array items
        msg = "Cells in col L starting with """ & VID & """" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
        MsgBox msg & " - L" & Join(found, ", L"), , "Total Found: " & f - 1
    Else
        MsgBox "No cells starting with """ & VID & """ found in col L", , "No matches"
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Even faster when using the [string versions](http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/stringopt2.html) of these functions

- `Left$()` `Mid$()` `Right$()` `Chr$()` `ChrW$()` `UCase$()` `LCase$()`
- `LTrim$()` `RTrim$()` `Trim$()` `Space$()` `String$()` `Format$()`
- `Hex$()` `Oct$()` `Str$()` `Error$`

They are more efficient (if `Null` is not a concern), as pointed out by [QHarr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50431901/find-the-cell-adresses-for-each-cell-that-starts-with-a-specific-number/50432260#comment87882917_50432260)

Comment: And Left$ should be even faster.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Findrow()
    Dim MyVal As String ' "2347" is a String
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim c As Range, myCells As Range

    MyVal = "2347"
    LastRow = cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).row

    Set myCells = Range("M2") 'initialize cells with a dummy cell certainly out of relevant one
    For Each c In Range("L2:L" & LastRow)
        If Left(c.Value2, 4) = MyVal Then Set myCells = Union(myCells, c) ' if current cell matches criteria then add it to cells
    Next
    If myCells.Count > 1 Then MsgBox "Cells " & Intersect(myCells, Range("L:L")).Address(False, False) & " have values starting with ‘2347’" ' if there are other cells than the dummy one then get rid of this latter and show their addresses
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!